# Is there an easy way to find out if my 0805 SMD components are ferrite beads?

Tags: components, ferrite-bead

I ordered SMD 0805 components among other items and I received a package with the SMD components but there is no description at all.

Also, there is no identification on the components itself.

Is there an easy way to find out if the components I have are ferrite beads? (that's the most logical type I can expect from the post).

When I used a DMM to measure the resistance it is 0 ohm, which seems normal for ferrite beads.

(note I don't have any EMI test, but I have an (old) oscilloscope if needed).

Comment: Does your scope have a test (square wave) output for probe adjustment?

Comment: A picture would help.  Zero ohms could be an inductor or a jumper - or your ferrite bead.

Comment: Reputable supplier of electronic components or ebay?

Comment: @PeterSmith yes I have a square wave generator on my scope.

Comment: @JRE I can make one in the evening, but it's just a 0805 components, with one both sides a 'terminal', metallic, and in the middle white (or grayish).

Comment: @Andyaka aliexpress

Comment: No further comment!

Comment: "White" sounds less like a ferrite (or even an inductor) and more like a resistor.

Comment: @JRE thanks for the remark

Comment: @Andyaka I understand, however, if I rephrase the question, it's not relevant if the supplier is from China or not. Assume the following case: I have a lot of SMD components, and they drop on the floor. I guess most components should have a code on it, but the code is depending on the manufacturer, and it's probably impossible to find back what code means what. Or is there a predefined code for all SMD components?

Comment: If they drop on the floor and there's a mixture of parts and those parts are not uniquely marked then I would put them in the trash unless they were high value parts. More than likely they would end up in the trash with a note to myself not to be so careless.

Comment: @Andyaka True indeed, putting all of them under a magnifying glass seems lot of work. But I'm glad some people found some tests to check ... in my case luckily, if I test one, they are all similar.

Comment: Resistors are usually marked, at least down to 0805 size.  Capacitors can be marked, but usually aren't.  I've never seen an SMD inductor with markings (no guarantee that they don't exist, but I've never encountered marked ones.)

Comment: @JRE Thanks for that remark.

Comment: Zero ohms and is obviously an inductance. (Why ferrite beads?? Does a magnet attract? Even if it does,that's not a complete indication of component type) You can use the 'ring' test to determine the L value very accurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your oscilloscope has a calibration output (to calibrate probes), you could use that signal (after having calibrated the probes!) to check with the frequency characteristics of the ferrite beads.

[image]
Source: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-an-oscilloscope/all

Comment: To be honest, I don't know if mine has, I will check, thanks for the picture and link.

Comment: Note the test signal is probably 1kHz and the bead is probably active at 100MHz so the effect will be tiny. [This might help](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/measuring-inductance-with-an-oscilloscope.150217/#post-1285181).

Comment: @rdtsc You should of course zoom in at the transients in this 1kHz signal

Comment: I hope my scope is that accurate (it's a very old Philips PM3110, I also have a PM 3253 but that one is barely usable). I will accept the answer because it seems the good way to test (but the test itself has to wait until I have some more time).

Answer (score 3):

A ferrite bead will measure close to zero ohms and will be strongly attracted to a permanent magnet.

If you have a spectrum analyzer with tracking generator, or at least a signal generator and oscilloscope, you can get an idea of the impedance (often measured at 100MHz).

Comment: I will try the magnet 'test'  (that one is easy) and do the test as Huisman specifies (seems similar as your proposal)

Comment: Upvoted, although I also tried a resistor and that is also attracted strongly, the other tip with the oscilloscope I will try when I have some more time.